# Will Geirim (proselytes) receive a future land allotment?

Tags: messiah, eretz-yisrael, real-estate, geirim

Will converts to the Israelite religion, also known as geirim or proselytes, **who have no land allotment in the land of Israel and can't permanently own Israelite land** receive a land allotment in the future when Moshiach comes?

Comment: The Torah says gerim do not inherit land rather they can take maaser at the same time poor people do. What makes you think there would be a change during moshiach times?

Comment: @Dude because the prophet Yechezkel - Ezekiel says so. See my answer.

Comment: @הראל please do not use מתיהדים for proselytes - many  explain that word in Esther to refer to people masquerading as Jews, not proselytes. (And is a popular explanation for dressing-up on Purim.) Though, admittedly, Rashi says מִתְיַהֲדִים. מִתְגַּיְּרִים:

Comment: @DannySchoemann "_because the prophet Yechezkel - Ezekiel says so._" If that is what made הראל think there would be a change during moshiach times, he should [have] state[d] so in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

The prophet Yechezkel - Ezekiel when discussing the division of the land in Moshiach times states in [47:22-23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.47.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> וְהָיָ֗ה תַּפִּ֣לוּ אוֹתָהּ֮ בְּנַחֲלָה֒ לָכֶ֗ם וּלְהַגֵּרִים֙ הַגָּרִ֣ים בְּתוֹכְכֶ֔ם אֲשֶׁר־הוֹלִ֥דוּ בָנִ֖ים בְּתוֹכְכֶ֑ם וְהָי֣וּ לָכֶ֗ם כְּאֶזְרָח֙ בִּבְנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל אִתְּכֶם֙ יִפְּל֣וּ בְנַֽחֲלָ֔ה בְּת֖וֹךְ שִׁבְטֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל׃ ‏
> You shall allot it as a heritage for yourselves **and for the proselytes who reside among you**, who will have begotten children among you. You shall treat them as Israelite citizens; they shall receive allotments along with you among the tribes of Israel.

> וְהָיָ֣ה בַשֵּׁ֔בֶט אֲשֶׁר־גָּ֥ר הַגֵּ֖ר אִתּ֑וֹ שָׁ֚ם תִּתְּנ֣וּ נַחֲלָת֔וֹ נְאֻ֖ם אֲ--י יֱ--ה׃‏
> **In whatever tribe the proselytes dwells with you, you shall give him his inheritance there**, says the Lord Gcd.

The Abarbenel (from a footnote on pg 480 of The Living Nach) elaborates:

> Having joined the ranks of Isreal during  its time of exile and suffering, the proselytes will share in the messianic promise and settle in the land of Israel after the Redemption

Comment: Excellent answer Danny. It isn’t so much a part of the question, but more about the process of becoming a full fledged convert, meaning bringing a Korban. Consider Hilchot Gerim from Mishneh Torah in the regard to the distinctions between Ezekiel 47:22 and Ezekiel 47:23. The ultimate common and contiguous donated land within the borders of the land of Israel is the destined portion of the male converts. That land also pertains to King Moshiach who is the heart of the whole nation.

Comment: You shall divide this land of yours for the tribes of Israel. 
You will cast a lottery of inheritance for the converts who converted (during exile) and resided among you (during exile) and had (male) children, from your inheritance. They will become like native-born Israelite citizens to you; (like) with you, they shall receive inheritance by lottery among the tribes of Israel.  
You will give his inheritance (the inheritance of the Converts) to the tribe in which the Convert dwells (meaning the tribe of the male converts)—declares L-rd G-d.

Comment: This lottery will take place after the Converts acquire the status of being a "complete Convert" by bringing their Korbanot, like Rambam poskins in Mishneh Torah, after the third Temple has been rebuilt and the Temple service has been reinstituted by King Moshiach. Prior to that act, they and their male children have no inheritance in the land of Israel because they are excluded from all other tribes like was the decision from Moshe Rabbeinu. This "bringing of the Korbanot of the Converts", is the final, physical, material expression of the ingathering of the exiles.

Comment: For reference, Mishneh Torah, Sefer Nashim, Hilchot Issuer Bia'ah, Chapter 13, Halachot 4-6.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly not. [Sifri, commenting on Bamidbar 10:29](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Bamidbar.78?lang=he), cites the verse from Yechezkel that Danny mentioned, but then interprets as follows:

> אל המקום אשר אמר ה' אותו אתן לכם – ואין לגרים בו חלק. ומה אני מקיים (יחזקאל מז) "והיה השבט אשר גר הגר אתו..."? אלא, אם אינו ענין לירושה – תניהו ענין לכפרה: שאם היה בשבט יהודה – מתכפר לו בשבט יהודה, בשבט בנימן – מתכפר לו בשבט בנימן. ד"א: אם אינו ענין לירושה – תניהו ענין לקבורה: ניתן לגרים קבורה בארץ ישראל
>
> "To the place that Hashem said I will give to you" - gerim do not have a portion in it. How do we explain the verse in Yechezkel? Rather, since it cannot be speaking about inheritance, we apply it to atonement: if a convert is among the tribe of Yehudah, he receives atonement together with the tribe of Yehudah; if with Binyamin, he receives atonement together with Binyamin.* Another explanation: since it cannot be speaking about inheritance, we apply it to burial, that gerim receive burial in Eretz Yisrael.

* [Netziv](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=40638#p=256) offers two interpretations: it's referring to when the Sanhedrin makes an error in halachah and they have to bring an offering on behalf of each tribe; or that it's talking about the atonement one receives for living in Eretz Yisrael, which will depend on the respective tribe's merits.

Comment: You should take a look at my comments to @DannySchoemann. The land that will become an inheritance to the 13th tribe, the tribe of male Gerim and their sons, is that portion given by all the tribes to their King (meaning King Moshiach), who is the heart of all Israel. Like Gerim, the King has a quality that is distinct from the individual. That is the distinction between Tzibbur and individual. This also pertains to the halachic concept of Tzibbur Lo Met צבור לא מת. See Ba'er Hetev on Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayim 90:11
and Steinsaltz on Temurah 15b:6

Comment: @YaacovDeane It's a nice vort and it would explain a lot, but is there any source for this point (that Moshiach will give away/reserve some of his portion for the gerim)?

Comment: Shavuah tov and Purim same’ach. You should look over the commentaries on Yechezkel that discuss the land given by all the tribes to the King. The concept is alluded to there as I recall.